# Pane is already set as root of another scene but i'm not sure how to fix it

Tags: java, javafx, illegalargumentexception

I wanted to make a button to restart a little game I made (in the game you must pick up a coin and get to the exit while a snake is trying to kill you), but now I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pane@2d5cc6c[styleClass=root]is already set as root of another scene
    at javafx.scene.Scene$9.invalidated(Scene.java:1110)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.setRoot(Scene.java:1072)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:347)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:194)
    at application.Main.startGame(Main.java:216)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:307)
    at application.Main.restart(Main.java:298)
    at application.Main.lambda$2(Main.java:276)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I guessed the button was the problem but apperently the whole pane is the issue. Here's the code that could cause this problem:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Pane root = new Pane();

    private static Button btnNewGame = new Button( "New Game?" );

    private Parent createContent() {
        root.setPrefSize( 1280, 720 );
        timer.start();
        return root;
    }

    void cleanup() {
        timer.stop();
        root.getChildren().clear();
    }

    public void startGame( Stage stage ) {

            Scene scene = new Scene( createContent() );

            btnNewGame.setOnAction( e -> {
                   restart( stage );
                });

            stage.setScene( scene );
            stage.setTitle( "ZZZZZnake - Von Christoph Gabauer" );
            stage.getIcons().add( new Image( Main.class.getResourceAsStream( "icon.png" ) ) );
            stage.setResizable( false );
            stage.show();
    }

    void restart( Stage stage ) {
        cleanup();
        start( stage );
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage ) {
        startGame( primaryStage );  
    }
}
```

Hope you can help me and thanks in advance.
Best regards from Bavaria

Christoph

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you should not call start() a second time. Maybe you just clean up all children of the primaryStage?

Comment: For all intents and purposes, the `#start(Stage)` method is the entry point of a JavaFX application; it's questionable to call it more than once. If you really want to replace the entire scene then create new objects instead of reusing old ones. Otherwise, work with the existing objects and simply reset their state. That being said, it'd be beneficial to separate the game state into a model.

Comment: @Slaw thanks for the Comment but can you put that as an answer with the code you would change?

Comment: At the very least, you should follow his advice on not calling the `public void start(Stage primaryStage)` any other place in your code.

Comment: Using nodes in 2 different places does not work in JavaFX. Since you're not creating a new `Pane` when `createContent` is called, the old one is reused. The exception message tells you what's wrong with that. Also it's a good idea to avoid `static`, if possible: There's no real reason for `btnNewGame` to be `static`.